# Query de dos conexiones distintas en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas noches estoy intentando hacer una query de tablas de conexiones distintas, tengo una conexión que es la habitual que se llama `mysql` y he creado otra que se llama `apolo`, necesito hacer un join con las dos.

```
$usuarios = DB::connection('apolo')->table('users')
                    ->join('clientes AS client', 'users.intranet_id', '=', 'client.id')
                    ->select('users.*', 'client.name')
                    ->get();
```

Como podeis ver me conecto a la conexión de `apolo` y quiero hacer un join con mi tabla de clientes de mi conexión habitual `mysql` que estoy haciendo mal, lo he realizado así muchas veces sin problema, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Saludos

Me arroja este error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'apolo2021.clientes' doesn't exist
```

Esta buscando la tabla clientes en la base de datos que no es.

**Edición**

Estoy probando así pero tampoco, no se si es por que en las dos bases de datos hay una tabla `users`.

```
$prueba = DB::Connection('apolo')
             ->table('users')
             ->join(DB::Connection('mysql'))                       
             ->table('clientes', 'users.intranet_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
             ->get();
             dd($prueba);
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), 1 passed in
```

Comment: ¿Tu código da algún error?, por favor da mas contexto del mismo

Comment: Hola @BetaM buenas noches, ya puse el error en la pregunta, se me olvido colocarlo. Esta buscando clientes en la BD que no debe

Comment: He probado de otro modo @BetaM pero no se que pasa??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función join no te sirve ya que de acuerdo a la documentación esa función no recibe por parámetro la conexión:

[Join Eloquent](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_join)

Puedes crear un modelo de la tabla Users indicando que debe usar la conexión apolo.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'apolo';
}
```

Luego haces la relación con la tabla clientes de uno a uno (entiendo que cada user esta asociado a un solo cliente):

```
class Users extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'apolo';

    /**
     * Get the client associated with the user.
     */
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Clientes::class, 'id','intranet_id');
    }
}
```

[Relación uno a uno en eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

También puedes mapear la relación en Clientes, sería:

```
class Clientes extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the User associated with the client.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::class, 'intranet_id','id');
    }
}
```

Al obtener el modelo debes poder usar la funcion client() o user(), dependiendo de cual modelo buscaste:

```
$user = Users::find(1)->client;
$cliente = Clientes::find(1)->user;
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu comentario, lo bueno que el modelo de users de la otra BD ya lo tenia creado, habitualmente lo creo por que lo necesito, pero no sabia hacer bien la relación, gracias funciono perfecto @zerocool